# Wrapping bootstrap / jquery widgets with ember.js and ember easyform

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, widget, multi-select

I'm trying to implement some widgets (Multiselect and Datetimepicker) in my ember.js application. Not reinventing the wheel, i would prefer existing widgets that work well in bootstrap context but they don't in emberjs / easyForm.

I created a [jsbin sample for multiselect](http://jsbin.com/eQAWizEb/2/edit), which works partially, but it is not displaying the element-list onclick. If manually add a css (see commented line), the list is displayed correctly but events are not handled by ember.

Could somebody tell me, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Here's an example using bootstrap-datetimepicker that I recently posted: https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/147#issuecomment-36207978

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with EasyForm so I'm not sure this would work for you, but I created a component and helper to wrap multiselect:

```
Ember.BootstrapMultiselect = Ember.Select.extend({
  multiple:true,
  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.$().multiselect(this.get('options'));
  },
  onSelectionChanged: Ember.observer('selection', function () {
    this.$().multiselect('rebuild');
  })
});
Ember.Handlebars.helper('bootstrap-multiselect', Ember.BootstrapMultiselect);
```

Comment: Can you also show an example of how to use this helper?

Comment: I'm using ember-cli, so replaced the last line with export default BootstrapMultiselect (and replaced Ember. with var in Line 1). Here's how I"m attempting to use it:  {{bootstrap-multiselect options=['Friday','Saturday']}}. I get Uncaught Error: You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process